# Pass Password to runas from Python

Tags: python, windows, passwords, runas

I need to run a file as another user without it prompting for a password, from my script. How is this done?

Comment: This may not be for something nefarious, but it sure sounds like it. Good luck with that.

Comment: Which OS are you targeting ... I mean ... using?

Comment: Actually, it isn't anything nefarious, @Justin Peel. Not targeting either, @Ben. It is actually for a legit application. It is using the Windows OS. I'm still learning about hacking etc. :) Know of any good resources?

Comment: You should just be able to use `popen`, provided you have the proper permissions...

Comment: check that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054128/using-python-to-open-cmd-and-automatically-enter-a-password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an executable program called [SANUR.EXE](http://www.commandline.co.uk/sanur_unsupported/index.html) that's made for just this kind of situation: you can use it to pipe in the password on the command-line, like this: `runas /user:domain\username cmd.exe | sanur mysekritpassword`.

Comment: the link is dead, and there are better alternatives than using that program. psexec is one, and sending chars to the input is another (see linked question)

Answer (score 0):

Have the user add whatever it is as a scheduled task with a specific name but no schedule, so it can only be invoked manually. They will need to enter the account credentials when creating the task, but only once. Then you can simply tell `schtasks` (Windows command line tool) to run it.