# Python: Give input for a subprocess

Tags: python, windows, input, subprocess, pipe

I have to create a new process with Admin privileges using a python script. I searched on the Internet about this topic and found out that I have to use `runas` command. For this command, I have to give an user and at runtime, the script will wait for the password and I want to do this as automatic as possible.

This is my code:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['runas', '/user:Armando', szCmdCommand], stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write('password')
```

Instead of `.write` I tried `p.communicate(input='password')` but it isn't working because it doesnt write the password. The only thing that happens is that the script doesn't wait for input. It automatically takes a wrong password and fails the execution of my command.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Do you really want to write your password in plaintext in a script?

Comment: Yes. That wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Programs that expect passwords to be entered usually do not use simple read from standard input (stdin) for this, but they control the terminal directly (as you can see in [source code of the `getpass` module](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/getpass.py)).

Use something other, for example:

- [Pass Password to runas from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011245/pass-password-to-runas-from-python)
- [Unable to supply password to runas from commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786511/unable-to-supply-password-to-runas-from-commandline)
- [Python subprocess.Popen as different user on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273939/python-subprocess-popen-as-different-user-on-windows)

Comment: Thank you. That would be exactly what I am searching for, but it doens't work. It says that `'sanur' is not recognized as an internal or external command`