# subprocess opens the program before prompting for the password

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, ssms, runas

I'm making a script to launch `SQL Server Management Studio` using `runas` command on `Windows` machine. When ran from `cmd` the command prompts user to enter the password and then starts the program.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

user = '/user:some_domain\\username'  # \ to escape special character
path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn/ManagementStudio/Ssms.exe'

process = Popen(['runas', '/netonly', user, path], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)  # launches 'ssms.exe'
process.communicate('password\n')  # never hit
```

In my case as soon as it hits the `process = Popen(...)` line it launches the `SSMS` without ever prompting for the password. Checking process in `Windows Task Manager` shows the same username in both cases, so I don't know if it's running on the correct domain. How can I address this?

Comment: runas.exe will only read the password from the console. Your options are to write it to the console input buffer via `WriteConsoleInput` or save the password in the user's credential vault by using the `/savecred` option (requires interactive password entry the first time).

Comment: @eryksun Unfortunately `/savecred` isn't an option as after trying it I recieve a message about trust issues. Would you mind giving an example of `WriteConsoleInput` as I don't see any in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleinput#requirements). I need to have `/netonly` as I'm accessing a machine on different domain.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44056313/205580) and my comments on it.

Comment: @eryksun `psexec` doesn't work for me as I don't need to run the process on a remote machine. I need to launch `SSMS` on local machine & connect to DB. I've tried to launch `cmd` and the send in the command an input. `process = Popen(['cmd.exe', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE])` and `process.communicate(input='runas ...')`, but that didn't seem to do anything useful.

Comment: Check again. I linked to the answer written by Jean-François Fabre, which shows how to use `WriteConsoleInput` in Python.